# Monterey not mounting encrypted volumes

Tags: macbook-pro, keychain, encryption, apple-silicon

I cannot get Monterey to decrypt volumes at boot on my M1 MacBook Pro.  I have this working on another Mac running Catalina where I'm using BootUnlock.  I initially installed it directly from the download but that was the x86 version, so I rebuilt it, cleaned down the remnants of the x86 version and re-installed the dual-architecture version:

```
root@samhain ~ # file /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/au.com.openwall.BootUnlock/*
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/au.com.openwall.BootUnlock/BootUnlock:   Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/au.com.openwall.BootUnlock/BootUnlock (for architecture x86_64):     Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/au.com.openwall.BootUnlock/BootUnlock (for architecture arm64e):     Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/au.com.openwall.BootUnlock/diskutil.xsl: ASCII text
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/au.com.openwall.BootUnlock/helper.sh:    Bourne-Again shell script text executable, ASCII text
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/au.com.openwall.BootUnlock/update.sh:    Bourne-Again shell script text executable, ASCII text
root@samhain ~ #
```

It had set the access to the volumes correctly:

[image]

However when I rebooted it and logged in it was asking for permission to access the Keychain:

[image]

Any ideas to get BootUnlock working or suggestions of an alternative tool or method?

### Update 1

I set up a Monterey VM on my Mac Pro (2019, x86) and installed BootUnlock—and it works.  On the face of it this is an M1 problem.  The log (`/var/log/BootUnlock.log`) on the MacBook Pro M1 has entries like this:

```
Trying to unlock volume "sTimeMachine" with UUID ED793E20-4F9D-4A8E-9185-B2735A1164B0 ...
NOTICE: could not find the secret on the System keychain, skipping the volume.
```

### Update 2

It's very simple really, the binary is being killed:

```
root@samhain ~ # /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/au.com.openwall.BootUnlock/BootUnlock
zsh: killed     /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/au.com.openwall.BootUnlock/BootUnlock
root@samhain ~ #
```

This happens when you attempt to run the wrong architecture but as shown above `BootUnlock` has both architectures.

Comment: Honestly, I'm struggling to find the use-case for this tool. You want the drives to unlock automatically at boot, without providing credentials? Why not just unencrypt them. Same end result.

Comment: Because if they weren't encrypted then they'd free to be read by everyone.  And don't forget you can't securely erase SSDs, so you shouldn't leave anything unencrypted on them.

Comment: If they're unlocked without user intervention at boot, then the only gain is once the drives are discarded. Anyone with access to the computer has access to the data on  the drives with an auto-unlock.

Comment: How is this different than just applying FileVault to them?

Comment: @MarcWilson: Two aspects: it's good practice to have separate volumes with quotas for non-OS data such as user data; I want a Time Machine within my MacBook and the only way to do that is with a separate volume (in a separate partition actually) which needs to be encrypted and I want it mounted at boot.

Comment: And, other than nothing, what do either of those have to do with making them FV volumes?

Comment: @MarcWilson As I said earlier: you don't want any encrypted volumes on an SSD.

Comment: @PhilipKearns Why wouldn't I want any encrypted volumes on an SSD?  *Un-encrypted*, we can have a conversation, your comment up-thread about secure erase is appropriate for that.

Comment: @PhilipKearns Regarding your update 2 (binary is being killed): When you compiled the tool, did you remember to codesign it afterwards?

Comment: @jksoegaard Oh, I have no idea what codesign is, so no I didn't.  Please advise.  Would it make sense for me to put a separate question in StackOverflow specifically on this?

Comment: @MarcWilson That was a typo: i don't want any *un*encrypted volumes on an SSD

Comment: @PhilipKearns I have answered now with an suggestion on how to codesign

Comment: I fixed BootUnlock to work with ARM-based Macs (I just recently got one).

Answer (score 2):

Apple Silicon Macs require that all executables are signed. When you run an unsigned executable, it is not allowed to run - and it will show up in the shell as "killed".

As you compiled the tool yourself, you have probably left out codesigning. You can do that after compiling by running this command in the Terminal:

```
codesign -s - /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/au.com.openwall.BootUnlock/BootUnlock
```

The "-" means that it will perform an ad-hoc signing. The resulting signature does not use a specific identity and the program will only be able to run on your own local machine. If you have either a developer subscription with Apple, or you have created a free certificate with your Apple ID, you can use that for signing instead.

**UPDATE:**

I have found the source repository for the program in question, and can see that the `BootUnlock` is not a new, unique binary - but rather just a copy of the built-in `/usr/bin/security` program. As that program is known to work and is codesigned appropriately, it would be a good idea to change the script to simply call `/usr/bin/security` instead of `BootUnlock`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work.  I tried `codesign -s -`; it said it was already signed.  I tried `codesign -f -s -`; it replaced the signature.  But it's still killing it.  In his build directory for BootUnlock he includes a build script which does `pkgbuild` and `productbuild` - maybe they sign it.   I can paste the build script into my question above if it would help.

Comment: Does that program have dependencies? (i.e. does it load in for example a shared library or framework?) - If so, those need to be codesigned as well. Try "codesign -vv /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/au.com.openwall.BootUnlock/BootUnlock" to show information about signing status.

Comment: This is really strange: it outputs two lines, `BootUnlock: valid on disk` and `BootUnlock: satisfies its Designated Requirement`.  That suggests its cert is not the reason it's being killed.

Comment: Does it have dependencies? Have you checked those?

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought the `-vv` would check that.  The binary is very simple (it's only 645k) and the process mainly uses scripts to carry out its tasks; those I understand very well.  In Solaris and Linux you can use `ldd` to show the libraries a binary depends on - is there a similar command in macOS/Darwin?

Comment: I'll give you an up-vote for the suggestion, even if it appears it's not the solution.

Comment: @PhilipKearns For this purpose, you can get similar results using "otool -L mybinary"

Comment: Have you tried looking at the system logs when you run the command to see if anything is logged there? - As you say it is script based - are you sure the scripts you're running do not run unsigned commands? - have you tried adding the program in System Prefereces > Security & Privacy > Privacy? (i.e. give it full disk access or whatever it needs to be able to work)

Comment: The scripts run fine: one of them calls BootUnlock but misinterprets the return as its having failed to find the password (an opportunity to improve them there, another day).  Good suggestion on the system logs, and I'll have a look at `otool -L`.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant that BootUnlock itself was a program that called out to scripts to do its job. I now realize that this is not a program you have written yourself, but rather an open source tool - and that the BootUnlock binary is simply a copy of the macOS supplied /usr/bin/security program - and not a new program at all. The open source repository includes a postinstall script that deliberately replaces the valid codesigning signature in this "security"-copy. Have you ensured that this step has actually been taken? - i.e. ensure that it is the new code signature on there.

Comment: Very good: I hadn't noticed that it's just `/usr/bin/security`.  I wonder could I just pop that into the script instead?  Why didn't the original author do that?  Regarding the signature: wasn't that what we were doing with `codesign` above.  It suggested the signature was valid.  Unfortunately my day job beckons…

Comment: It wasn't the same no - I wasn't aware that you didn't actually build a binary, but rather just copied a system one. If you just run codesign on a binary that's already signed, nothing happens - you need to apply a special force parameter to force it to replace existing signatures.

Comment: Why they do it that way instead of just calling out to security is not immediately clear to me. Perhaps it is just to make it part of the same .app so the code signing signature checks out, and so that the program does not need permissions to call out to external commands -- not exactly sure why that would be a problem though.

Comment: Have you considered modifying the script to leave out the call to BootUnlock and just hardcode in your password? - That way you can test whether the rest of the tool works before working more on BootUnlock itself.

Comment: The scripts definitely work, tested thoroughly on x86 (that's what I use on my Mac Pro), it's only the binary that's the problem.  When I get back to it, I'll try replacing `BootUnlock` with `/usr/bin/security`.

Comment: Well, you haven't tested it on this particular system - so I would advise doing that first - it might uncover something unexpected.

Comment: I have it working: I replaced `BootUnlock` with `/usr/bin/security` in `helper.sh` and changed the appropriate Keychain entry.  (Which also means the scripts are working fine.)  I have done it for one volume and will add more tomorrow.  It's not a fix *per se* just a really ugly workaround, but thanks for noticing that BootUnlock was just a wrapper.

Comment: Perfect - wonder why it was done with a copy in the first place :-)

Comment: @jksoegaard, this was done to avoid a situation when an authenticated user can mount an encrypted volume they are not supposed to mount by abusing `security`, which is available to everyone on the system.  I am the author of the BootUnlock wrapper, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer *per se*, it's just a rather ugly workaround.  If I get a fix I will post it.  With the help and insight of @jksoegaard I figured out the best workaround for the BootUnlock problem.

1. Download BootUnlock from its site
2. Install the package as normal
3. There's a bug in the install that if you select the wrong volume you
   can't cancel it (I must try fixing that bug), so make sure you
   select the correct ones.  It will ask you for the passwords of each
   Volume.

Once it's installed as root you will need to edit:

```
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/au.com.openwall.BootUnlock/helper.sh
```

Replace `${0%/*}/BootUnlock` with `/usr/bin/security`

Open Keychain, select System on the lefthand side, and find the entries for your disks.  For each disk open its entry, for example:

[image]

Select 'Access Control' (you will be asked for your password) and you will see
BootUnlock there already.  Press '+' to add another application.  Navagate to
the root of the boot disk, press Shift-Command-`.` to see all the files.  Navigate to `/usr/bin/security` and add it:

[image]

Press 'Save Changes' (you will be asked again for your password).

Reboot and check that the disks are indeed unlocked and mounted.

Comment: I am not sure that I understood what bug you are referring to (could you please raise an issue on GitHub, if there is still an issue?).  As re: granting `/usr/bin/security` this permission -- it should be noted that this makes it possible to unlock the drive to anyone who is authenticated to the system.  Avoiding this permission to `security` was one of the goals of the BootUnlock wrapper.

Comment: I wrote that 18 months ago so having difficulty visualising the bug, but if I see it again I'll use GitHub to report it.  You are right in all you say about giving `/usr/bin/security` such permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty was that on Apple silicone the binaries are built for an architecture only Apple can sign binaries for.  The BootUnlock has been updated to work on Apple silicone with the latest release (by leveraging Rosetta for /usr/bin/security and signing the x86_64 part of the binary only).

The reason BootUnlock is using a copy of the `/usr/bin/security` is to follow the least privilege principle -- we want to have the disk password available only to BootUnlock and not to every user on the system who has access to `/usr/bin/security`.

Comment: I had guessed that was the reason for writing the wrapper.  Thanks updating BootUnlock, I'll try it out when I get a chance.